# How to Curl API with more than one IP address on Windows Server?

Tags: virtualbox, ip, hyper-v, network-adapter, windows-server

I purchased a real server with 10 dedicated IP addresses and Windows server on it to run my website on it. My app try to call an API and I need to send each request with one IP at a time. That's why I have to change IP in each request on application layer (curl syntax : "X_FORWARDED_FOR: ".$randIP,"REMOTE_ADDR: ".$randIP which $randIP is a random IP from a list of my IP's). But every time my request outgo from same IP (my master IP) which is dedicated to my Network Interface Card.
Is there any solution to send each request from one IP?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.

Outgoing connections go from your router, whose IP is dictated by the internet
supplier (ISP), so is not something that you can change.

The 10 IP addresses you purchased allow outsiders to reach you in 10 different ways,
and so allow your server to distinguish between 10 different types of requests.
This way you can setup 10 websites with a different IP per each one, where all 10 are
served by this one server.

Comment: Thanks. As I understand PHP Curl works at application Layer and IP on Network Layer. So Changing IP's on CURL doesn't work until you can change IP on network packets. So some people said installing some VPN services like Squid may help. What's your opinion about that? @harrymc

Comment: With a VPN your IP address will appear to be that of the VPN server that you are connected-to. Your IP address is always what appears on your connection to the internet. Without a VPN, this is the address allocated to your router by the ISP (what you call main IP). With VPN this is the address allocated to you by the VPN provider.